# Using Debug.Assert in VB.Net aplication

Tags: vb.net, reference, .net-assembly

I am writing my first VB.net app and want to include Debug.Assert functions.

When I do this,

```vb
Debug.Assert(LBound(arry) = 0)
```

I get the error

> BC30451: Debug is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I know that Debug is supposed to be in the namespace "System.Diagnostics", and in C# I can use it if I include "Using System.Diagnostics;" at the top of the source file.

In VB.Net, there is no similar Using statement that I can find, so I think I need to add System.Diagnostics to References.

However, in the Reference Manager, System.Diagnostics is not listed. I enabled similar sounding references, such as System.Diagnostics.Tracing, but they do not define a Debug object.

What should I do if System.Diagnostics is not available in RefernceManager and I need to reference that namespace?

Comment: There is no such thing as "referencing a namespace". I suggest that you read this: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html

Comment: Thank you.  I read that and learned that I can use the Imports statement in a VB.Net file like I would use Using in C#.

I added Imports System.Diagnostics at the top of the file, and the error went away. 

I'm still wondering whether I would have to add this Imports statement at the top of every single code file, and why I can't add a Reference to System.Diagnostics in the Reference Manager.  That seems to work for everything else.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=netframework-4.8) is the documentation for the `Debug` class in .NET Framework 4.8. Note the assembly and the namespace. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=net-6.0) is the same documentation for .NET 6. Note that assembly and the namespace. In .NET Core, which .NET 5 and later are based on, you reference assemblies by installing NuGet packages. ALWAYS read the documentation.

Comment: Please be a little nicer. I have done nothing but read documentation on this for several hours am still doing it.  I will get there.  In the meantime, any succinct answers would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidBangs Please make sure to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and set it to be the default for new projects. It lets Visual Studio help you with problems like this.

Comment: The whole idea is to only have necessary namespaces as many objects/properties/methods have the same name. Otherwise if there are too many imported you have to qualify which one you mean. **Note it is only about saving typing**. `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(LBound(arry) = 0)` would work and is what you would do if using it once.

Comment: When you choose a vb.net project you get `<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>` in the Application.Designer.vb file. In this case you would not have to add the Imports to each file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm good for now.
This article explains more about importing namespaces in VBA.
[How to: Add or remove imported namespaces (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-imported-namespaces-visual-basic?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Project%20Designer%2C%20click%20the%20References%20tab.,add%20the%20namespace%20to%20the%20Imported%20Namespaces%20list.)

I learned that that you can use the Imports statement in VB.Net to import a namespace on a per file basis and how to get more control over project imported namespaces by double-clicking on My Project and linking References. From user1792293 I learned that one should always say "import a namespace" instead of "reference a namespace."  Thank you for that.

Comment: All that information is included in the blog post I linked to, as well as an explanation of why. When someone asks for help, you provide it, they ignore it and then ask you to be nice, that can be less than encouraging.

Comment: VBA isn't the same as VB FYI (your link is for the .NET version of VB, not VBA, so it is relevant to the question and answer).

Comment: Thank you to anyone who wanted to help.  I found the information I needed in a document that was specifically about VB.net.  I understood the whole time what it meant to import a namespace, and was only confused about the VB.Net speicific syntax and that the namespace I wanted to import wasn't listed in the Reference Manager.  I found it listed in Project Configuration References instead, so I am fine.